# How to bold a string response in asp.net while exporting datatable to .xls file

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Hi this is my code and it is working fine.
I have a datatable and I am converting it into .xls file.
I have used this `Response.Write(tab + "<b>" + dc.ColumnName + "</b>");`
I want to make it BOLD

```
string attachment = "attachment; filename=" + filename;
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                string tab = "";
                foreach (DataColumn dc in dataTable.Columns)
                {
                    Response.Write(tab + "<b>" + dc.ColumnName + "</b>");
                    tab = "\t";
                }
                Response.Write("\n");
                int i;
                foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
                {
                    tab = "";
                    for (i = 0; i < dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Response.Write(tab + dr[i].ToString());
                        tab = "\t";
                    }
                    Response.Write("\n");
                }
                Response.End();
                Response.Flush();
```

But this didn't worked please help.

Comment: no there is no error, i want to make the text bold. Thats it

Comment: You can see the code I added into my answer. Works 100%. Do not see your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<span style=...>` instead of `<b>`:

```
Response.Write(tab + "<span style='font-weight:bold'>" + dc.ColumnName + "</span>");
```

Haven't tested this myself; if it still isn't working, change it all to use `<table>`, `<tr>` and `<th>` / `<td>` html tags - I know from experience that this works to export a "pseudo-Excel" file. And then you can put the style on the `<th>` / `<td>` tags.

Comment: Hi @Peter this didn't worked either. It is printing the whole as a string

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this:

```
//Write in new column
Response.Write("<Td>");

//Get column headers  and make it as bold in excel columns
Response.Write("<B>");
Response.Write(column);
Response.Write("</B>");
Response.Write("</Td>");
```

**Update**

Here the code and sample datatable with some dummy data, just tested and it works fine:

```
  //export to excel datatable
            var dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.Columns.Add("ID");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Name");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Country");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("City");

            dataTable.Rows.Add("1", "Micheal", "USA", "Washington");
            dataTable.Rows.Add("2", "Smith", "UK", "London");
            dataTable.Rows.Add("3", "Martin", "AUS", "Sydney");


            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();

            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.Write("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\">");
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=testExport.xls");
            Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            Response.Charset = "";

            //Set Fonts
            Response.Write("<font style='font-size:10.0pt; font-family:Calibri;'>");
            Response.Write("<BR><BR><BR>");

            //Sets the table border, cell spacing, border color, font of the text, background,
            //foreground, font height
            Response.Write("<Table border='1' bgColor='#ffffff' borderColor='#000000' cellSpacing='0' cellPadding='0' style='font-size:10.0pt; font-family:Calibri; background:white;'> <TR>");

            // Check not to increase number of records more than 65k according to excel,03
            if (dataTable.Rows.Count <= 65536)
            {
                // Get DataTable Column's Header
                foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
                {
                    //Write in new column
                    Response.Write("<Td>");

                    //Get column headers  and make it as bold in excel columns
                    Response.Write("<B>");
                    Response.Write(column);
                    Response.Write("</B>");
                    Response.Write("</Td>");
                }

                Response.Write("</TR>");

                // Get DataTable Column's Row
                foreach (DataRow dtRow in dataTable.Rows)
                {
                    //Write in new row
                    Response.Write("<TR>");

                    for (int i = 0; i <= dataTable.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        Response.Write("<Td>");
                        Response.Write(dtRow[i].ToString());
                        Response.Write("</Td>");
                    }

                    Response.Write("</TR>");
                }
            }

            Response.Write("</Table>");
            Response.Write("</font>");

            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
```